# Changing class attribute not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a simplified running code to show my problem:

```
class c_event():
  cl_attr = None
  
  def __init__(self, mystring):  
    print(self.cl_attr)
    if self.cl_attr is None:
      self.cl_attr = mystring
    print(self.cl_attr)
    
var1 = c_event('123')
var2 = c_event('456')    
print(var1.cl_attr)
print(var2.cl_attr)
print(c_event.cl_attr)
```

I am under the assumption that a class attribute defined like I did is common, read- and writeable by all instances of that class. So I expected to get an output of:

```
None
123
123
123
123
123
123
```

Instead I get:

```
None
123
None
456
123
456
None
```

What is the (thinking) mistake I made?
***Edit: Chepners answer helped understanding. Here is the code that does what I want:

```
class c_event():
  cl_attr = None
  
  def __init__(self, mystring):  
    print(c_event.cl_attr)
    if c_event.cl_attr is None:
      c_event.cl_attr = mystring
    print(c_event.cl_attr)
    
var1 = c_event('123')
var2 = c_event('456')    
print(var1.cl_attr)
print(var2.cl_attr)
print(c_event.cl_attr)
```

Comment: When you write the attribute, it writes to the current instance, it doesn't modify the class attribute.

Comment: You’re setting an instance attribute. If you want to set a class attribute, you need to set it on the class.

Comment: The class attribute is used as a default when you try to read `self.cl_attr` if the current instance doesn't have the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change a class attribute by assigning to the attribute via the class itself, not an instance. `__init__` is creating a new *instance* attribute that subsequently shadows the class attribute.

```
class c_event():
  cl_attr = None
  
  def __init__(self, mystring):  
    print(self.cl_attr)
    if self.cl_attr is None:
      type(self).cl_attr = mystring
    print(self.cl_attr)
```

It's not clear that you should be modifying a *class* attribute like this in the first place. Basically, `cl_attr` is remembering the value used to create the *first* instance of `c_event`.

If you really just want to set the instance attribute, the class attribute isn't necessary at all:

```
class c_event:
    def __init__(self, mystring):
        self.attr = mystring
```

Comment: This is the best answer, The context i think is the confusion around class attributes vs instance attributes. When I first started with Python this was incredibly confusing.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't get emphasized enough that classes in Python don't actually define instance attributes; they just define *methods* which create them via assignment. (The practice of `dataclasses` to use names annotated at the class level to define `__init__`, among other things, don't help with the confusion.)